# Unsupported operand types for 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, nonetype

I am tasked with getting this to work, but the initial port scan code wasn't working on outdated Python versions. I am extremely new to Python coding and hopefully someone can point out what is causing the above error.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from socket import *
from datetime import datetime

START_PORT = 1
END_PORT = 1025

target = input(">>> Enter target's IP address: ")

start_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print("\nScan started at %s \n") % (start_time)

def scan_target(target, port):
    try:
       return_code = 1

       s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK STREAM)

       err_code = s.connect_ex((target,port))

       if err_code == 0:
           return_code == err_code

       s.close()

    except:
        print("Error: Could not establish connection!")
        sys.exit(0)

    return return_code

for port in range(START_PORT, END_PORT)
    return_code = scan_target(target, port)

    if return code == 0:
        print( "*** Port %d: OPEN") % (port)

end_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
duration = end_time - start_time
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the *fulll text* of the traceback that you are getting.

Comment: It's a typo; you wrote `print("\nScan started at %s \n") % (start_time)` when you meant `print("\nScan started at %s \n" % start_time)` (removing the close paren after the string, and the open paren before `start_time`). The former printed without applying formatting substitutions, then tried to use the return value of `print` (`None`) with the modulus operator.